# Check spinner status

Tags: java, android, spinner

can anyone tell me how can I check if the spinner selected or not I used this 
code but it doesn't work !

======================== after updating ====================================

```
//=====================================================================================         
       //Duration Time + Spinner for Time Conditions + Retrieving time Part#1
        CaseDurationH.clearChildFocus(null);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.feedbacktypelist, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        CaseDurationH.setAdapter(adapter);
        CaseDurationH.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

             public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {


                 int i = CaseDurationH.getSelectedItemPosition();
                 strH = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();

                 try { 
                  intH = Integer.parseInt(strH);
                  intHInMin=intH*60;
                } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { 

                } 


                if(i==2){

                     CaseDurationM.setEnabled(false);

                 }

                 if(strH.equals("hr0"))

                         {

                 CaseDurationM.setEnabled(true);

                     }



                 if(strH.equals("hr1"))

                         {

                 CaseDurationM.setEnabled(true);

                     }





                 if(strH.equals("hr2"))

                         {

                     CaseDurationM.setEnabled(false);  

                     }


             }

             public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 } });

//=====================================================================================         
     //  Duration Time Part#2
        CaseDurationM.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

             public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {


                 int i = CaseDurationM.getSelectedItemPosition();
                 strM = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();


                 try { 
                      intM = Integer.parseInt(strM);

                    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { 

                    } 


             }

             public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub


             } });

//=====================================================================================  


// For Disabling The Buttons
    void updateButtonState() {


        if(  CheckSpinner(CaseDurationH ,  CaseDurationM) && checkEditText2(CaseName) && checkEditText2(CaseAge) && CheckRButtons(RBMale, RBFemale) ) {
        Nextb.setEnabled(true);}
        else {Nextb.setEnabled(false);}

            }
//=============================================================================
// For Spinner
private boolean CheckSpinner(Spinner caseDurationH2, Spinner caseDurationM2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    boolean CheckingSpinners= false;
    if (caseDurationH2.isSelected() && caseDurationM2.isSelected() )
    CheckingSpinners= true;    
    return CheckingSpinners;
}
```

===============================================================================

Question:

- I want to make the button disable until the user select an item from one of these spinners ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put listner for spinner  `setOnItemSelectedListener`  and in check it in  `OnNothingSelected(...)`

see this Example http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2010/05/spinner-view-android-beginner-dev.html

Comment: what happens and tell me what you want actualy

Comment: there are onnothingselect method write there